# What's the correct way to load and open a component inside a modal dialog in Angular4 --

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, elementref

I have a component called NewCustomerComponent and I want to load and display it through a modal popup in another page/component when a button is clicked. I have written the relevant bit of code [or so it seems]. But I am getting the following error --

```
    this._childInstance.dialogInit is not a function
at ModalDialogComponent.dialogInit (modal-dialog.component.js:65)
at ModalDialogService.openDialog (modal-dialog.service.js:26)
at OrderNewComponent.newCl (order-new.component.ts:85)
```

My code is pretty simple too, in the component where I am trying to open the modal popup.
I'll just post the relevant portions --

```
    import { Component, Inject, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef } from 
             '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { CustomerSearchService } from '../../../shared/services/customer- 
       search.service';
    import { ICustomer, Customer, CustomerD } from 
       '../../../shared/models/customer';
    import { ModalDialogModule, ModalDialogService, IModalDialog } from 'ngx- 
      modal-dialog';
    import { NewCustomerComponent } from 
      '../../../components/popups/customer/customer-new.component';


    @Component({
        selector: 'order-new',
        templateUrl: './order-new.component.html' 
    })

    export class OrderNewComponent {

    public reference: ComponentRef<IModalDialog>;

    constructor(private cusService: CustomerSearchService, private http: 
        Http, private modalService: ModalDialogService, private viewRef: 
        ViewContainerRef) {

    }

   ngOnInit(): void {

   }


  ** this is where I am trying to load the newcustomercomponent and open it 
  in the popup. not working.     
  newCl() {
     this.newC = true;
     this.exiC = false;

     this.modalService.openDialog(this.viewRef, {
        title: 'Add New Customer',
        childComponent: NewCustomerComponent
     });
   }

 }
```

** edits. NewCustomerComponent code added for reference.

```
    import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, 
       ChangeDetectorRef, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, AfterViewInit } 
       from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { ICustomer, Customer } from '../../../shared/models/customer';
    import { UserService } from '../../../shared/services/UserService';
    import { IModalDialog, IModalDialogOptions, IModalDialogButton } from 
         'ngx-modal-dialog';
    @Component({
       selector: 'new-customer',
       templateUrl: './customer-new.component.html'
    })

    export class NewCustomerComponent implements IModalDialog {
       model: Customer = new Customer();
       errors: any;
       submitResponse: any;
       actionButtons: IModalDialogButton[];

       constructor(private userService: UserService, private http: Http) {
                  this.actionButtons = [
                  { text: 'Close', onAction: () => true }
               ];
       }


      ngOnInit() {

      }

      dialogInit(reference: ComponentRef<IModalDialog>, options: 
                       Partial<IModalDialogOptions<any>>) 
      {
                // no processing needed
      }

     createCustomer() {
          this.userService.createCustomer(this.model)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(
            (response: any) => {
                this.submitResponse = response;

                if (response.success) {
                    console.log('New customer added!');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Unable to add customer!');
                }
            },
            (errors: any) => this.errors = errors
        );
    return false;
}

     cancelClicked() {

     }

   }
```

What did I do wrong here? Has it got something to do with the element reference I added in terms of the viewRef? Which portion is erroneous? What about that child component? Does it require to have some specific configuration/markup/component for this to work? I am very new to angular; I am not sure whatever the reason is.

Kindly help me rectify this scenario.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: check to this link http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

Can you please ensure that the `NewCustomerComponent` is implementing the `IModalDialog`interface. Also, if this is not the case can you please share the code of `NewCustomerComponent` as well.

**edits**

Looks like you have not defined the dialogInit method in the `NewCustomerComponent` and it didn't pop up before as you have not implemented the interface `IModalDialog`. I would request you to define the dialogInit method in the component class as suggested on the [link](https://github.com/Greentube/ngx-modal#usage).

Comment: hi there @AshishKhandelwal, I have added the NewCustomerComponent code. Pl take a look. 

Please note -- I am showing this same newcustomercomponent component elsewhere also, in simple normal manner, just as a normal page. Hope, adding the IModal interface won't hamper that in any manner. Just confirming, Thanks,

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury I have edited the answer. Have a look.

Comment: hi @AshishKhandelwal thanks for the link. reading it now - will try to do it as per the guidelines in the doc; if farther complications I will revert back.

Comment: hi @AshishKhandelwal there is only 1 problem happening now - upon clicking the button, the modal is showing but for a very fraction of second only and then escaping away. kindly check the updated section of the code for the newcustomercomponent that I have implemented. why could it be happening? I experimented with value of true false both for onAction()=> Not working.

Comment: nope I am still stuck with this. I have done several changes; pl take a look if you please. @AshishKhandelwal.The dialog is displaying but closing almost immediately. automatically.There's no console errors showing so I cannot see for any message/indication there either. Someone who knows the reason, pl help.